# Return in Catch Statement

Tags: java, return, try-catch

At the following program, in case I remove the return statement from:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
        return;
```

It shows me an error inside the do while loop, that the local variable `fin` might not have been initialized. Can someone explain me why is this happening?

```
import java.io.*; 
class Stock { 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
            throws IOException { 
        int i; 
        FileInputStream fin; 
        try { 
            fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]); 
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
            return; 
        } 
        // read characters until EOF is encountered 
        do { 
            i = fin.read(); 
            if(i != -1) System.out.print((char) i); 
        } while(i != -1); 
            fin.close(); 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Just set `fin = null` when you declare it.

Comment: @markspace Then he'll get a NullPointerException at run time if that code path is exercised.  Probably he just needs to leave the `return` statement in.

Comment: Great thanks! it works properly with fin = null and the return removed from catch. unfortunately I am still missing what return does and helps us keep the fin initialized

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the `return` statement, you get:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
        throws IOException { 
    int i; 
    FileInputStream fin; 
    try { 
        fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]); 
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
    } 
    // read characters until EOF is encountered 
    do { 
        i = fin.read(); 
        if(i != -1) System.out.print((char) i); 
    } while(i != -1); 
        fin.close(); 
    }
```

Now if `FileInputStream` throws an exception, it doesn't return a result, and `fin` doesn't get initialized.  The `catch` block handles the exception and prints a message, but then the code continues, and the next thing it tries to execute is `i = fin.read()`.  Since the compiler figures out that there's a possible way to get to this statement without initializing `fin` or assigning anything to it, it won't compile the program.

If you put the `return` back in, this can't happen, because the `catch` block will cause `main` to return, and you can't get to `fin.read()`.

Comment: so the program will stop at catch, as the return will cause main to return, without needing to proceed to the do while loop where the fin has definitely to be initialized correct?

Comment: @user3923997 Yes, I think you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

The exception could have been thrown in the call in the try block, so no value will have been assigned to the variable `fin`.  Without the return statement, the subsequent use of the uninitialized `fin` variable causes the compiler to complain.

With the return statement, if the `fin` variable is never initialized, it is never used, either, so the compiler is okay with that.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, unfortunately I am still missing how return works here. In case of an exception the statement fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);  will not be executed right? then the program will move to the catch statement, printing File Not Found. But what return does that helps us keep the fin variable initialized?

Comment: With the return statement, an exception means the `fin` variable is never used, so it doesn't matter that it's never initialized.

Comment: The `fin = new FileInputStream(args[0])` is executed. It is source of the exception. And return in the catch block just ends your program, so the execution doesn't reach the point where `fin` variable is used.

Answer (score 1):

Why compiler complain

```
-  if your main() encounter the exceptions it will pass try catch block and never get the 
    chance to initialize fin variable  
 -  Compiler knows that program may end up with throwing an exception which has high chance
    in order to avoid any fruther issue it will not complie
```

I advise you to do this

```
 - use try catch block with resources since Java 7 since Class `FileInputStream` is     `closable`
  - put everything in a good order
```

code:

```
try(FileInputStream fin =new FileInputStream(args[0]) ) { 
          while ((content = fin.read()) != -1) {
            // convert to char and display it
            System.out.print((char) content);
        }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
            return; 
        } ...
....
..
```

Source:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you want clarification or to critique the author, a comment is the appropriate method.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils how come this is not an answer when it is getting rid the issue? and make the code more readable?

Comment: Question: "Can someone explain me why is this happening?" You answer with another question: "...why do not you do this[?]" Questions don't answer questions.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils if the OP uses the try catch block with resources, it shoudl not worried about how to close it and worried about if fin is intilized or not? am i right?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils what is wrong to give another idea or way to the OP?

Comment: I think you need to first answer a question that is posed; explain to op the problem. *Then* pointing op in another valid direction is indeed OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58996/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-chief-two-pencils).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils could you please take a look at my update and see how it is?

Answer (score 0):

An exception could occur in `new FileInputStream(args[0]);`, which would cause fin to not have been initialized.

Try using a default value for fin:

```
fin = null;
```

Then later, check to make sure it is not null:

```
if (fin != null)
{
   do { 
       i = fin.read(); 
       if(i != -1) System.out.print((char) i); 
      } while(i != -1); 
      fin.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is encountered while instantiating the FileInputStream, then control moves to the catch block before a value is stored in the variable fin. Without the return statement in place the program would continue execution into the do/while loop, where a method (read) would be called on the uninitialized variable, resulting in an error.